# A-Frame: Limit the number of faces and vertices on models

Tags: performance, 3d, three.js

I'm having trouble with the performance of A-Frame and all I tried had no effect. On the A-Frame website in [Best Practices - Performance](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/best-practices.html#performance) the following is mentioned:

> Limit the number of faces and vertices on models.

[This model](https://www.file-upload.net/download-13039676/blocks.html.html) has nearly 100k vertices and 30k faces. How can I reduce the number of faces and/or vertices? It is a requirement that the user can interact with every box in the model separately, e.g. by changing its color or transparency or position. Is there a way to create a mesh or whatever and still having full interaction with every element on its own?

Besides that, I have no idea how to improve performance. The scene has no lights, textures, collisions, raycasters and all the other heavy stuff. These are just some boxes ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in this scene is not the number of vertices or faces (100k and 30k respectively are fine), but the size of the scene graph and the number of GPU draw calls. There are 2400 `<a-box/>` elements, each requires a separate draw call, and that is too many. The number of draw calls should be as low as possible, ideally < 100.

To keep all 2400 boxes interactive, you'll need to either (1) create a custom component that puts all boxes into a single [`THREE.BufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry) and changes vertex positions and colors within `geometry.attributes.position` and `geometry.attributes.color`, or (2) use a technique like [instancing](https://github.com/takahirox/aframe-instancing). Both will require some custom JS, not just HTML markup, as they're not built into A-Frame as components.

Comment: the second link points to the issues section of three.js, you meant something like [this](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing.html) ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't used BufferGeometry because [three.js documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry) says "This makes BufferGeometry best-suited for static objects where you don't need to manipulate the geometry much after instantiating it." which is not my use case. But as far as I understand, BufferGeometry is just less comfortable but has the same features as Geometry, right?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski oops, thanks! I meant aframe-instancing but your link is also relevant.

Comment: @naraesk — `THREE.Geometry` is nearly deprecated, but yes it would also work. BufferGeometry is a bit less comfortable to work with, but (despite the documentation) can certainly be used for dynamic objects. Each attribute in your BufferGeometry can use `.dynamic`, `.updateRange()`, and `.needsUpdate`, see [BufferAttribute docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferAttribute).